# How do I count numbers that contain one digit, but not another?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I recently came across an interview question which although had an immediately obvious solution, I struggled to find a more efficient one.

The actual question involved counting numbers from `a` to `b` (up to `2^64`) which satisfied having either the digit `6` or `8`, but not both. They called it a 'lucky number'. So for example:

```
126 - lucky
88 - lucky
856 - not lucky
```

The obvious thought was to brute force it by testing each number between `a` and `b` as a string, to check for the relevant characters. However, this was prohibitively slow as expected.

A much better solution that I tried, involved first computing all the 'lucky numbers' which had the number of digits between the number of digits that `a` and `b` have (by counting possible combinations):

```
long n = 0;

for (int occurrences = 1; occurrences <= maxDigits; occurrences++) {

    n += (long) Math.pow(8, digits - occurrences) * choose(digits, occurrences);
}

return 2 * n;
```

and then using the brute force method to compute the number of extra lucky numbers that I had counted. So for example, if `a = 3` and `b = 21`, I could count the number of `1` and `2` digit lucky numbers, then subtract the count of those in `[1, 3)` and `(21, 99]`.

However, although this was a massive improvement, the brute force element still slowed it down way too much for most cases.

I feel like there must be something I am missing, as the rest of the interview questions were relatively simple. Does anyone have any idea of a better solution?

---

<sup>Although I have tagged this question in Java, help in any other languages or pseudocode would be equally appreciated.</sup>

Comment: I don't know the solution but, instead of testing each number within the interval, I would generate all possible lucky numbers from a to b and count them (actually, there's no need to store each lucky number, just incrementing a counter would do it)

Comment: You could go the opposite way and generate the numbers as strings, then parse them to get the integer value. The parsing is not efficient, but it will generate far fewer candidates to check. Or generate just the marker values (e.g. "0...08" and "9...98") and figure out how many values that contains (e.g. "xxx8" has "999" values for the "xxx" digits) and add to the total, with special cases for upper and lower bounds (e.g. minus `lower` and minus (999-`upper`) ). Sorry don't have time to derive an actual answer, hopefully that's enough to give a direction.

Comment: An important optimization: your combinatorial sum is in fact `9**n - 8**n`.

Comment: @fps I was thinking the same, but I have no found a "pattern" to do that... did you?

Comment: @Eugene It's combinatorics... you'd need to count all possible permutations with one 6, then with two 6, etc, up to the number of digits. Same for 8 and sum to the total count... Then, count all possible permutations with 6 and 8 and subtract from the count of 6 plus the count of 8... And you'd need to be careful with the lower and upper bounds... Quite nasty...

Comment: @fps yeah, that I figured. I hoped there would be a trick I did not think of... thank you for getting back on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you are at the right track. The gut feeling is that dealing with the `a` and `b` separately is easier. Making a function `count_lucky_numbers_below(n)` allows

```
return count_lucky_numbers_below(b) - count_lucky_numbers_below(a);
```

The combinatorial approach is definitely a way to go (just keep in mind that the sum is actually equal to `9**n - 8**n`, and there is no need to compute the binomial coefficients).

The final trick is to recurse down by a numbeer of digits.

Lets say `n` is an `N`-digit number, and the most significant digit is 5. Each set of `N`-digit numbers starting with a smaller digit contributes `S = 9**(N-1) - 8**(N-1)` to the total; you immediately have `5*S` of lucky numbers. To deal with the remainder, you need to compute the lucky numbers for the `N-1`-digit tail.

Of course, care must be taken if the most significant digit is above 5. You need to special case it being 6 or 8, but it doesn't seem to be too complicated.

Comment: can I ask you to post an example to this answer please? I think that you are right, but an example from A to Z would make this a far better resource. thank you!

Comment: I managed to use your logic to find a remarkably fast solution, however it still isn't as concise as I would have liked. Maybe I have missed a simplification, so please let me know if it wasn't what you had in mind. Regardless, thank you for pushing me in the right direction (or at least some sort of direction!).

Comment: @Eugene Hopefully my answer provides said resource (if that's what was intended from *this* answer)

Answer (score 1):

In the end the answer from @user58697 pushed me in the right direction towards finding a solution. With my (albeit extremely primitive) benchmark, it handles `1` to `2^63 - 1` in less than 2 nanoseconds, so it is definitely fast enough. However it is still more verbose than I would have liked, especially given that I was originally expected to write it in half an hour, so I feel like there is still an easier solution that gives comparable performance.

```
long countLuckyNumbersBetween(long a, long b) {

    return countLuckyNumbersBelow(b) - countLuckyNumbersBelow(a - 1);
}

long countLuckyNumbersBelow(long n) {

    return countNumbers(n, 6, 8) + countNumbers(n, 8, 6);
}

/**
 * Counts the natural numbers in [0, {to}] that have {including} as a digit, but not {excluding}.
 * {excluding} should be in (0, 9] or -1 to exclude no digit.
 */
long countNumbers(long to, int including, int excluding) {

    if (including == -1) return 0;

    if (to < 10) {

        if (to >= including) {

            return 1;
        } else {

            return 0;
        }
    }

    int nSignificand = significand(to);
    int nDigits = countDigits(to);

    long nTail = to % (long) Math.pow(10, nDigits - 1);

    // The count of numbers in [0, 10^(nDigits-1)) that include and exclude the relevant digits
    long bodyCount;
    if (excluding == -1) {

        bodyCount = (long) (Math.pow(10, nDigits - 1) - Math.pow(9, nDigits - 1));
    } else {

        bodyCount = (long) (Math.pow(9, nDigits - 1) - Math.pow(8, nDigits - 1));
    }

    long count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nSignificand; i++) {

        if (i == including) {

            if (excluding == -1) {

                count += Math.pow(10, nDigits - 1);
            } else {

                count += Math.pow(9, nDigits - 1);
            }
        } else if (i != excluding) {

            count += bodyCount;
        }
    }

    if (nSignificand == including) {

        count += 1 + nTail - countNumbers(nTail, excluding, -1);
    } else if (nSignificand != excluding) {

        count += countNumbers(nTail, including, excluding);
    }

    return count;
}

int significand(long n) {

    while (n > 9) n /= 10;
    return (int) n;
}

int countDigits(long n) {

    if (n <= 1) {

        return 1;
    } else {

        return (int) (Math.log10(n) + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

2<sup>64</sup> = 18446744073709551616

We can represent the number as a sum of components (one component per every digit position):

```
  18446744073709551616              associated range of numbers
  ————————————————————      ———————————————————————————————————————————
  0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  =>  [00000000000000000000;09999999999999999999]
  17xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  =>  [10000000000000000000;17999999999999999999]
  183xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  =>  [18000000000000000000;18399999999999999999]
  1843xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  =>  [18400000000000000000;18439999999999999999]
  18445xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  =>  [18440000000000000000;18445999999999999999]
  ...
  1844674407370955160x  =>  [18446744073709551600;18446744073709551609]
  18446744073709551616  =>  [18446744073709551610;18446744073709551616]
```

If we could compute the amount of lucky numbers for every component, then the sum of the amounts for every component will be the total amount for 2<sup>64</sup>.

Note that every component consists of a prefix followed by `x`s.
Imagine that we know how many lucky numbers there are in an n-digit `xx..x` (i.e. numbers `[0..0 - 9..9]`), let's call it `N(n)`.

Now let's look at a component `18445x..x`. where `18445` is a prefix and an n-digit `xx..x`.
In this component we look at all numbers from `18440xx..x` to `18445xx..x`.
For every item `1844dxx..x` we look at the prefix `1844d`:

- if prefix contains no `6` or `8`, then it's the same as `x..x` without prefix => `N(n)` special numbers
- if prefix contains `6` and no `8`, then `x..x` cannot contain `8` => `9ⁿ` special numbers
- if prefix contains `8` and no `6`, then `x..x` cannot contain `6` => `9ⁿ` special numbers
- if prefix contains `6` and `8` => `0` special numbers

Now let's compute `N(n)` — the amount of lucky numbers in an n-digit `xx..x` (i.e. in `[0..0 - 9..9]`).
We can do it iteratively:

1. `n=1`: there are only 2 possible numbers: `8` and `6` => `N(1)=2`.
2. `n=2`: there are 2 groups:

   - `8` present: `8x` and `x8` where `x` is any digit except `6`
   - `6` present: `6x` and `x6` where `x` is any digit except `8`

   => `N(2)=4*9=34`.
3. `n=3`: let's fix the 1st digit:

   - `0xx` — `5xx`, `7xx`, `9xx` => `8 * N(2)`
   - `6xx`: `xx` are any 2 digits except `8` => `9²`
   - `8xx`: `xx` are any 2 digits except `6` => `9²`
     => `N(3) = 8*N(2) + 2*9²`.
4. `n=k+1` => `N(k+1) = 7*N(k) + 2*9ᵏ`

Here is an implementation (not 100% tested):

```java
public final class Numbers {

  public long countLuckyNumbersBelow(BigInteger num) {
    if (num.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("num < 0: " + num);
    }
    var numberText = num.toString();
    var result = 0L;
    for (var digitPosition = 0; digitPosition < numberText.length(); digitPosition++) {
      result += countLuckyNumbersForComponent(numberText, digitPosition);
    }
    return result;
  }

  private long countLuckyNumbersForComponent(String numberText, int digitPosition) {
    var prefixEndIdx = numberText.length() - 1 - digitPosition;
    var prefixHas6s = containsChar(numberText, '6', prefixEndIdx);
    var prefixHas8s = containsChar(numberText, '8', prefixEndIdx);
    if (prefixHas6s && prefixHas8s) {
      return 0;
    }
    var result = 0L;
    for (var c = numberText.charAt(prefixEndIdx) - 1; c >= '0'; c--) {
      var compNo6s = (!prefixHas6s) && (c != '6');
      var compNo8s = (!prefixHas8s) && (c != '8');
      if (compNo6s && compNo8s) {
        result += countLuckyNumbers(digitPosition);
      } else if (compNo6s || compNo8s) {
        result += power9(digitPosition);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  private static boolean containsChar(String text, char c, int endIdx) {
    var idx = text.indexOf(c);
    return (idx > 0) && (idx < endIdx);
  }

  private long[] countLuckyNumbersCache = {0L, 0L};

  /**
   * Computes how many lucky numbers are in an n-digit `xx..x`
   */
  private long countLuckyNumbers(int numDigits) {
    if (countLuckyNumbersCache[0] == numDigits) {
      return countLuckyNumbersCache[1];
    }
    long N;
    if (numDigits <= 1) {
      N = (numDigits == 1) ? 2 : 0;
    } else {
      var prevN = countLuckyNumbers(numDigits - 1);
      N = (8 * prevN) + (2 * power9(numDigits-1));
    }
    countLuckyNumbersCache[0] = numDigits;
    countLuckyNumbersCache[1] = N;
    return N;
  }

  private long[] power9Cache = {0L, 1L};

  /**
   * Computes 9<sup>power</sup>
   */
  private long power9(int power) {
    if (power9Cache[0] == power) {
      return power9Cache[1];
    }
    long res = 1;
    var p = power;
    if (power > power9Cache[0]) {
      p -= power9Cache[0];
      res = power9Cache[1];
    }
    for (; p > 0; p--) {
      res *= 9;
    }
    power9Cache[0] = power;
    power9Cache[1] = res;
    return res;
  }
}
```

---

BTW it took me half a day, and I have no idea how is that possible to complete it in 30 minutes.
I guess your interviewers expected from you to demonstrate them your thought process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result of my attempt.

First, let me explain a little bit what logic I used.

I used formula `S = 9N — 8N` (mentioned in [the user58697's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68188207)) to compute how many of N-digit numbers are lucky.
How to get this formula:

- for N-digit numbers there are `10N` numbers in total: `N` digits, each can take one of 10 values: `[0-9]`.
- if we only count numbers without `6`, then each digit can only take one of 9 values `[0-5,7-9]` — it's `9N` numbers in total
- now we also want only numbers with `8`.
  We can easily compute how many numbers ***don't*** have both `6` and `8`: digits in these numbers can only take one of 8 values `[0-5,7,9]` — it's `8N` numbers in total.
  As a result, there are `S = 9N — 8N` numbers which have `8` and no `6`.

For numbers with `6` and without `8` the formula is the same.
Also numbers without `6` do not intersect with numbers without `8` — so we can just sum them.

And finally, since we know how to count lucky numbers for intervals `[0;10N]`, we need to split the interval `[0; our arbitrary number]` into suitable sub-intervals.
For instance, we can split number `9845637` this way:

| Sub-interval | Prefix | Digit | N-digit interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `0000000 - 8999999` |  | `0 - 8` | `000000 - 999999` |
| `9000000 - 9799999` | `9` | `0 - 7` | `00000 - 99999` |
| `9800000 - 9839999` | `98` | `0 - 3` | `0000 - 9999` |
| `9840000 - 9844999` | `984` | `0 - 4` | `000 - 999` |
| `9845000 - 9845599` | `9845` | `0 - 5` | `00 - 99` |
| `9845600 - 9845629` | `98456` | `0 - 2` | `0 - 9` |
| `9845630 - 9845637` |  |  |  |

Now we can compute the number for every sub-interval (just keep attention to digits in prefix — they might contains `8` or `6`) and then just sum those numbers to get the final result.

Here is the code:

```java
  // Special value for 'requiredDigit': no required digit
  private static char NIL = Character.MAX_VALUE;

  public static long countLuckyNumbersUpTo(BigInteger number) {
    if (number.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("number < 0: " + number);
    }
    var numberAsDigits = number.toString();
    return countNumbersUpTo(numberAsDigits, '6', '8') + countNumbersUpTo(numberAsDigits, '8', '6');
  }

  // count all numbers in [0;'numberAsDigits'] which have 'requiredDigit' and no 'excludeDigit'
  private static long countNumbersUpTo(String numberAsDigits, char requiredDigit, char excludeDigit) {
    var highDigit = numberAsDigits.charAt(0);

    if (numberAsDigits.length() == 1) {
      return (requiredDigit != NIL)
          ? ((highDigit >= requiredDigit) ? 1 : 0)
          : numDigitsInInterval('0', highDigit, excludeDigit);
    }

    var tailDigits = numberAsDigits.substring(1);
    var result = 0L;

    // numbers where the highest digit is in [0;`highDigit`)
    var numGoodDigits = numDigitsInInterval('0', (char) (highDigit - 1), excludeDigit);
    var containsRequiredDigit = (requiredDigit != NIL) && (highDigit > requiredDigit);
    if (containsRequiredDigit) {
      result += totalNumbers(tailDigits.length(), NIL);
      numGoodDigits--;
    }
    if (numGoodDigits > 0) {
      result += numGoodDigits * totalNumbers(tailDigits.length(), requiredDigit);
    }

    // remaining numbers where the highest digit is `highDigit`
    if (highDigit != excludeDigit) {
      var newRequiredDigit = (highDigit == requiredDigit) ? NIL : requiredDigit;
      result += countNumbersUpTo(tailDigits, newRequiredDigit, excludeDigit);
    }

    return result;
  }

  private static int numDigitsInInterval(char firstDigit, char lastDigit, char excludeDigit) {
    var totalDigits = lastDigit - firstDigit + 1;
    return (excludeDigit <= lastDigit) ? (totalDigits - 1) : totalDigits;
  }

  // total numbers with given requiredDigit in [0;10^numDigits)
  private static long totalNumbers(int numDigits, char requiredDigit) {
    return (requiredDigit == NIL) ? pow(9, numDigits) : (pow(9, numDigits) - pow(8, numDigits));
  }

  private static long pow(int base, int exponent) {
    return BigInteger.valueOf(base).pow(exponent).longValueExact();
  }
```